# How to deal with the return value of setData() with curator

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

If I want to update data in Zookeeper with

> client.setData().forPath(“/demo/path”, “other data”.getBytes())

will it succeed if

1. The ZooKeeper is good
2. The client is good
3. The path exists
4. You have the right

for that I have read an article, it says that only N servers of 2N+1 servers think the update operation succeed , then it is succeed, if there are less than N servers think it OK, will it return FAIL, and how can I deal with these situation

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/12/observers-making-zookeeper-scale-even-further/

Answer (score -1):

When u set data using "client.setData().forPath(“/demo/path”, “other data”.getBytes())" .......It will return you a stat structure if data write is successful .

1. If the node does not exit it will throw an exception . So It is
   always advisable to check "client.Exits()" before you set the data .
2. When the client has No ACL permission then it will be mentioned in
       Stat structure.

Internally 1st data is written to the master and then to other slaves.
If you have an ensemble of 2N+1 servers ..you need at least N servers running for that ensemble to function .

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: so the update will fail when I do all right just for the ZooKeeper update process may not succeed

Comment: In case N servers are not running in an ensemble of 2N+1 servers ...update will fail.